# Get total with vat in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have two tables 
sales >>>

[image]

And sale_details

[image]

I want a my sql query, where it makes sum of each sale group, and if there is  any vat, add_vat than according to that (vat,add_vat) percentage it adds that amount and make total.

Sorry for my language.

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried some code yet or you want someone to code for you?

Comment: I tell you what, you give it a try, and if you get some problems come back and ask what you have done wrong. **SO is not your source of free programmers**

Comment: I know guys it is not source of free programmers, But I don't know how to tackle this problem.

Comment: try some code,if you get problem then ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT s.*, SUM(IF(sd.sale_id = s.id, sd.amount,0)) AS amount, FORMAT(IF( (s.vat + s.add_vat) > 0 ,(SUM(IF(sd.sale_id = s.id, sd.amount,0)))*((s.vat + s.add_vat+100)/100), SUM(IF(sd.sale_id = s.id, sd.amount,0))),2) as total FROM sales AS s LEFT JOIN sale_details AS sd ON s.id = sd.sale_id GROUP BY s.id
```